# Setting CheckBox.Checked state to True - "Input String was not in Correct Format"

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, boolean

I'm saving a boolean variable in an MS-Access database, (although interestingly, as I added it programmatically, it's showing in the DB as 0 or -1, rather than a tickbox?), and when loading in the data into a form, I have the following code:

```
cbNoCharge.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(fTable.Rows(0).Item("freeDelivery"))
```

However, this is erroring, saying

> Input string was not in a correct format

This is confusing me? Despite the initial DB value being a boolean anyway, I'm then converting it to one just to make sure of it. Why is a value of 'True' or 'False' not working as a boolean?

I also tried it as

```
If fTable.Rows(0).Item("freeDelivery") = True Then
    cbNoCharge.Checked = True
End If
```

But the same thing happened? What on Earth is going on?!

**EDIT**

I added the following line as a test:

```
Dim bFree As Boolean = fTable.Rows(0).Item("freeDelivery")
```

Which accepted the *exact* same field as boolean fine. So, I then tried

```
cbNoCharge.Checked = bFree
```

And the error occurred again.

**EDIT 2**

After following the advice of @VisualVincent, I added in his code to check that the value was in fact True, or False - As seen here, it is True.

[image]

Comment: Create a variable for your value: `Dim bFree As Object = fTable.Rows(0).Item("freeDelivery")` then inspect it to see what it actually holds: `MessageBox.Show(bFree.ToString())`, then post the result here. By doing so you'll be able to see whether it _actually is_ `True` or `False`, or if it's a completely different value.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yup, see edit. It's True for sure.

Answer (score 0):

if its a text box field you should be inputting Y or N to the field. not telling it to be checked or not checked. being checked on the database table only is a representation via display not the actual data. if its a check box in access then input `"Y"` AS STRING then it should check the box.

or you can use 1 or 0, 1 = checked, 0 = not checked.

Comment: The initial value is saved from `cbNoCharge.Checked`, so the `CheckBox` is setting the Boolean itself, then when loading the data back in, it's failing to go back to the same boolean value.

Comment: you need to set the field in ACCESS database as a tickbox field?? have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming because the `CheckedChanged` event of the `CheckBox` was triggering another method, and the error was in that method, rather than the `CheckBox` itself.

Debugging a bit deeper and more thoroughly led me to find this.